# hostvars on a temp group in a ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, hostvars

I am trying to preserve a command output from one dynamic host group to another one but get a variable is undefined error in my ansible playbook.

My playbook is dynamically getting the primary and secondary hosts by running a command. I want to use the output that I get from the secondary host on the primary with a when statement. Here's what I have.

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  tasks:
   - name: run curl command to determine primary/secondary
     command: /tmp/status.sh
     register: apis_op
   - name: run curl command to determine primary/secondary
     debug: var=apis_op.stdout_lines

   - name: If node is primary add to primary
     add_host:
       name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
       groups: temp_primary
     when: apis_op.stdout == "primary"
   - name: run curl command to determine primary/secondary
     debug: var=groups

   - name: If node is secondary add to secondary
     add_host:
       name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
       groups: temp_secondary
     when: apis_op.stdout == "secondary"
   - name: run curl command to determine primary/secondary
     debug: var=groups

- hosts: temp_secondary
  tasks:

   - name: Run schell script
     command: /tmp/runthis.sh
     become: yes
     become_user: root
     register: op

- hosts: temp_primary
  tasks:

   - name: Run schell script
     command: /tmp/testthis.sh
     become: yes
     become_user: root
     when: hostvars['temp_secondary']['op'] == "{false}"
```

When I run this I get a `hostvars['temp_secondary'] is undefined` error. Can I not use hostvars with temporary/dynamic host groups?

Comment: Task you register never persist from one play to another. You have to use a `set_fact` for this. So, run you command, register the output then use a `set_fact` to assign the registered output to a "new" variable. Then you're good to go.

Comment: thanks for the response. So, do i just do 


```- hosts: temp_secondary
  tasks:

   - name: Run schell script
     command: /tmp/runthis.sh
     become: yes
     become_user: root
     register: op
  set_fact:
    sec_state: "{{hostvars['localhost']['op']}}"  

- hosts: temp_primary
  tasks:

   - name: Run schell script
     command: /tmp/testthis.sh
     become: yes
     become_user: root
     when: "{{ sec_state }}" == "{false}"
```

Comment: Comments are not meant to receive large portions or code not to add specific info meeded to answer your question. Please [edit](/posts/68535394/edit) your question instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. @Zeitounator. I'll correct that as soon as I have a good direction to proceed.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Would you be able to help with the set_facts, please?

Comment: Hostvsrs is a dictionary which keys are hostnames. Temp_secondary is a group name so you won't get an entry for it. For set_fact, you can push the result in the same variable name 'op' for simplicity.